# Copy value to clipboard via Javascript command inserted in Address Bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, address-bar, clipboarddata

I'm able to get the current time of a Youtube playing video via inserting this JavaScript command to the address bar:

`javascript:alert(document.querySelector('video').currentTime);`

What I'm looking for is to get this video current time value to clipboard instead of displaying it within an alert box.

---

I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying to clipboard is easiest done using a lightweight open-source Javascript library.  [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) and [clipboard-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-js) both work in my experience.